# How to bind events on font awesome icons?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I want to bind the `click` event on a font awesome icon. Yet the icon itself is not clickable, only when I insert additional text, that text becomes bound.

How do I bind the icon itself?

```
<span class="icon-star">
    only this text is clickable, the icon itself is not
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('span.icon-star').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this));
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Is it out of the question to give the span a width/height in CSS? (You'd need `display:block` or `display:inline-block`)

Comment: Just to point out as well - your selector is asking for all `.icon-star` elements that are **children** of spans, whereas I think you want `span.icon-star`.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis It's not out of the question an it did indeed fix the problem. You may add this as an anwer for me to upvote and accept :) I'll edit the example code jQuery selector.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis For clarification: The "display:inline-block" fixed the problem. The false jQuery selector was only a question typo and had no further relevance.

Comment: OK great, glad it fixed it! Will add an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed above, giving the span a `block` or `inline-block` layout will fix the issue. As to why this happens with non-standard fonts, I'm not entirely sure, but it could be due to the fact that the browser doesn't recognise the character and therefore assumes the `span` tag is empty, thus collapsing it to 0 width and height.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution I used which seems to answer the question more clearly, binding just the icon, no other text needed.  Just wrap it in a `span` where you set the id.  Here is an example:

```
<span id="menuOpen">
  <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
</span> 

 $("#menuOpen").click(showMenu);
```

Hope that can help someone out.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to write onClick directly into i tag as this:

```
<i class="fa fa-navicon" onClick="functionName()"></i>
```

Yes, after hours testing, above solution got things done, and then I know that may be awesome icon issue, and a search brought me here.